# ¿Porque matplotlib me dibuja la nueva gráfica encima de la vieja?

Tags: python, django, matplotlib

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto de `django` el cual empleo la librería de `matplotlib`. En teoría he creado un filtro donde eliges el día y y "nodo" que quieres graficar y con esta info se ejecuta un script de `python` que junto con `pandas` y `matplotlib` se crea una gráfica.

Los valores de "nodo" y "dia" llegan correcto al script, y este genera bien el gráfico, lo único incorrecto es que en vez de sobrescribir la antigua imagen (con el gráfico anterior) dibuja las nuevas líneas encima. A continuación muestro una imagen de cómo queda.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cómo podeis ver cada línea equivale a un día diferente, porque se ha ido superponiendo las diferentes pruebas que he hecho. ¿Alguien puede decirme donde fallo?

A continuación adjunto código

```
def bateria2(node, day):
    csv_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..\\data\\csv\\dataframe.csv')
    df = pd.read_csv(csv_path)

    mes, anyo = 12, 2019
    new_df = df[(df['Dia'] == day) & (df['Mes'] == mes) & (df['Año'] == anyo) & (df['Node name'] == node)]

    if len(new_df) > 0:
        #os.remove('static\\img\\bateria2.png')
        x = new_df['Hora[UTC]'].tolist()
        y = new_df['Bateria'].tolist()

        title = 'Carga/Descarga de la batería día '+str(day)+'/'+str(mes)+'/'+str(anyo)+' de '+str(node)
        plt.title(title)
        plt.xlabel('Hora [UTC]')
        plt.ylabel('Batería')
        #plt.legend((y)(node))

        plt.plot(x,y)
        plt.xticks(x, rotation='vertical')

       plt.savefig('static\\img\\bateria2.png',transparent=True)

        return 1

    else:
        return 0
```

Básicamente es acceder al fichero `.csv` que contiene la info, filtrar según los datos que yo quiero. Y si el nuevo dataframe generado tiene datos crear la gráfica para finalmente guardarla.

Un saludo, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Después de `plt.savefig(...)` hay que borrar explícitamente el plot con `plt.clf()`.

Cuando se emplea matplotlib fuera de django, hay que hacer `plt.show()` para enseñar el plot en una ventana. Al cerrar la ventana, matplotlib automáticamente borra todo el plot. (Por eso si quieres guardar una imagen, se hace antes de llamar `plt.show()`.) Sin el `plt.show()` matplotlib no sabe si uno quiere seguir añadiendo al plot o empezar uno nuevo.